# Send a email already created in a window with a macro Outlook Python

Tags: python, email, outlook

I'm trying to automatize Outlook with python with win32com.client in python.

I have already a Macro that creates me a email, with all the subject and attached files.

The problem is that when I try to automatize it with Python, i don't know how to select the window that the macro open with all the info, and put the address to whom i want to send.
Example:
I want to send it to "Albert" all the emails that has number "1234" in attach files.

Also, i get error `" AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'To' "`

```
outlook = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
mail = outlook.ActiveWindow().Display()

print(type(mail))

mail. To = "Albert@gmail.com"


mail. Send()
```

Code from VBA is : (i deleted some details that are not important)
'Generate MailID

```
strMailID = GenerateMailID
```

'Generate xls file

```
 strFileName =Environ$("temp") & "/file directory"
```

'Create mail and attach xls file

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail

    .Subject = "DETAILS FROM EXCEL "
    .HTMLBody = "DETAIILS  "
    .Attachments.Add strFileName
    .UserProperties.Add "MailID", 1, False, 1
    .UserProperties("MailID") = strMailID
    .Display
```

Comment: OK, so you create an email in VB and want to access it in Python? Do use `Application.ActiveInspector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `Application.ActiveWindow` will return either `Explorer` or `Inspector` object, and you only want the latter. The current inspector is returned by `Application.ActiveInspector`.

And once you have an `Inspector` object, use `Inspector.CurrentItem` to retrieve the message being composed.

Thirdly, if you alreay have code that creates the message, why not simply call `MailItem.Display` to show it to the user? And if the message is shown in an inspector, why do you need to call `MailItem.Send` instead of letting the user click the Send button when they are ready? You really need to post your code that creates the message.

Comment: Hi Davis, thank you now i can select the current email. I want to send various emails with filtered columns from a Excel. I want to do a loop that auto-filter the report (I've already done it) and send it when the in column "a" number is 1234 send it to "x" person, and the loop would be like that. 
I will put the code from VBA Below in another comment

Comment: "Current" meaning currently being displayed by Outlook? There can be more than one. I don't understand why you break your code into two - one creates and displays the email, another is populating its properties. Why nto do both from either place?